# stdin restoring after processing

Tags: c, shell, stdin, restore

I have a function. I use `pipe()` and then change `stdin` and `stdout` with `close()` and `dup()`. I am trying to save the handle, but something goes wrong.

N-number of elements are in array `**arr`, which is an array of arguments for the shell's pipe. `*i` is used to index the elements in `**arr`.

```
int extraFd;

int conveer(char **arr,int * i,int N){
    char **args = NULL;
    key_t target_pid;
    int j = 0,fd[2];

    while((*i) < N && strcmp(arr[*i],"|") &&    
        strcmp(arr[*i],"<")   && 
        strcmp(arr[*i],">")   && 
        strcmp(arr[*i],">>")  && 
        strcmp(arr[*i],"&&")  &&
        strcmp(arr[*i],"&")   &&
        strcmp(arr[*i],";")   &&
        strcmp(arr[*i],"||")  &&
        strcmp(arr[*i],"(")   ){
        j++;
        args = realloc(args,sizeof(char *) * j);
        args[j-1] = arr[*i];
        (*i)++;
    }
    args = realloc(args,sizeof(char *) * (j+1));
    args[j] = NULL;                                 

    if( (*i) < N && strcmp(arr[(*i)],"|") == 0){    
        (*i)++;
        pipe(fd);
        if ( (target_pid = fork() ) ){          
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1],1);
            close(fd[1]);
            execvp(args[0],args);
        }
        else{                                       
            close(fd[1]);
            close(0);
            dup(fd[0]);
            close(fd[0]);
            return conveer(arr,i,N);
        }
    }
    else{                                           
        if ( target_pid = fork() ){
            execvp(args[0],args);
        }
        else {
            close(0);
            dup2(extraFd,0);
            close(extraFd);
            return 1;       
        }
    }
}

...
extraFd = dup(0);
check = conveer(arr,&i,N);
...
```

The function `conveer` should process the input, which is a string, but it just terminates without processing anything. What's wrong?

Comment: I was attempting to save your question, but it's impossible. I cannot figure out what you were asking.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying but shouldn't save the return value from `dup(fd[0]);` ?

Comment: Then call `dup2(extraFd,0);` seems strange as well

Comment: dup(fd[0]); - i set the input from; pipe; dup2(extraFd,0); - i try to reset the old input(i saved it in the beginning:extraFd = dup(0);)

Comment: Which book are you reading? Any reasonable MCVE should show that you understand all of these functions have return values which should be checked when debugging an issue. I guess whatever book you're reading might not be working for you... `args = realloc(args, ...)` is ***always*** wrong.